# "Notes" related list is missing for PersonEducation object

Tags: related-list, contentnote

We enabled notes in setup. Most objects have "Notes" in the related list. However, it is missing for PersonEducation.

From the documentation, LinkedEntityId in ContentDocumentLink does support the PersonEducation object. I used "New Note" action and was able to create a Note on the PersonEducation record. However, I can't see it on the screen because I don't have a related list.

I also did a SOQL query to make sure the note I created is actually saved to ContentNote and it did.

Any ideas on how to enable the "Notes" related list for this object?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to. It's something that isn't added to the layout items available for this object (PersonEducation) *internally*. You can see a [similar known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002KMdcQAG) for Health Cloud objects (including PersonEducation) that were missing *other* standard related lists.

Your best bet is to put in a support case in hopes to create a known issue and help prioritize that change being done.